# Command line translator

Tags: command-line, software-recommendation, translation

Is there a Command line translator for Ubuntu that has multiple languages?
With languages need English, Japanese, Chinese, Vietnamese, Korean, etc
Also nothing using Google works anymore.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

perhaps you can try the python script found [here](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1087457). It uses the google translate API.

Edit: seems that that api is a paid service now. Maybe you can use the oneliner from commandlinefu

```
 translate(){ wget -qO- "http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/services/language/translate?v=1.0&q=$1&langpair=$2|${3:-en}" | sed 's/.*"translatedText":"\([^"]*\)".*}/\1\n/'; }
```

Edit 2: try using libtranslate-bin available from the repositories

example usage:

```
 echo "hello" | translate-bin -f en -l
```

and to use google translate:

```
 echo "what are you doing" | translate-bin -s google -f en -t fr
```

and to convert kanji to romaji

```
echo "what are you doing" | translate-bin -s google -f en -t ja | iconv -f utf8 -t eucjp | kakasi -i euc -w | kakasi -i euc -Ha -Ka -Ja -Ea -ka
```

Comment: none of the google ones work anymore

Comment: I edited my post.

Comment: is there a way to get romanized Japanese?

Answer (score 0):

Recently I needed to do the same thing (albeit under Windows) and came across this question. I managed to compile libtranslate under windows, but I coulden't get it to work for various reasons (it failed to load `services.xml` no matter what I did).

I asked [this](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/11919/command-line-japanese-english-machine-translation) question and got an answer. The suggested answer was to use [Translate Shell](http://www.soimort.org/translate-shell/) which is just a single `sh` file. I had to tinker a bit to have it run on Windows the way I want, but there should be no problem using this tool on Ubuntu (in worst case scenario you'll have to install some dependencies).

Like libtranslate, Translate Shell also uses Google Translate.